# Unexplained timeouts for capybara find

Tags: ruby, xpath, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have tried searching for a span with an id  in a number of ways....

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="unique_span"]/span[1]').click
find(:css, '#unique_span').click
find(:css, '#unique_span> span.additional.unique.span.classname')
find('span#unique_span').click
find("span[id='unique_span']").click
```

In each event I get a timeout error and lock chrome

```
.rb:17
And I access system
                        # features/step_definitions/system/systemaccess.rb:2
  Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
```

I have confirmed that the span is visible and is not in an iframe.  In either case, I should get an element not found error.

What should I be looking for here?

Comment: You may to capture a screenshot to check what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'sleep' before your capybara finder and see if that helps.  If it does, then you should use an rspec expectation prior to using the finder.  Capybara sometimes doesn't cooperate well with very Ajax-y apps like those built in AngularJS.